# Запрос без обновления страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Есть форма, в ней texarea и кнопка, как сделать так, чтоб запрос выполнялся без обновления страницы, а texarea обнулялась?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так.

```
<script>
  function post(self) {
    $.post('/script.php', $(self).serialize(), function (data) {
      alert(data);
    });
    $('textarea', self).val(''); // или .empty()
    return false; // запрещаем передачу формы стандартным способом
  }
</script>
<form onsubmit="return post(this);">
  <textarea name="area"></textarea>
  <button></button>
</form>
```

Comment: скрипт не запрашивает :<